# How to connect plc with eternet port?

Tags: c#, .net, ip, tcpclient, plc

I have a plc with eternet port.

I want to connect between PLC and my PC through TCP/IP.

How can it be done ?

```
using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient())
 {
   Console.WriteLine("Attempting to connect to the server ","on port 8000.");

   client.Connect(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.97"), 8000);
 }
```

Comment: You need to connect to the server's IP adress. `127.0.0.1` is "localhost" - that is _the same machine you are calling from_. That of course also means that your PLC needs to have a server running at port 8000.

Comment: i set my Ip address,192.168.1.97

Comment: What do you mean by "my ip address"? You have your PC and the PLC. Both need to have their respective IP-Adresses. If you want to connect from the PC to PLC, you need to provide the PLC's IP-Adress to the Connect-Method and run it from your PC.

Comment: Note that this code will tear down the connection as soon as `Connect` has returned.

Comment: You need a server/client socket implementation in the PLC. You need to implement a protocol on both (if not exists)

Comment: @Fildor , yes, I have PLC's IP-Adress: 192.168.1.97 . I set this ip for connect to plc.

Comment: Alright, now if you do not get any exceptions, it probably worked. Again, given you actually have a service running on PLC that is listening on TCP/8000.

Comment: I get error ""A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 192.168.1.97:8000""

Answer (score 0):

The question needs a bit more details... but I will write some considerations:

1. a modern PLC typically can manage an TCP/IP stack and most has already an integrated webserver at some port (80?), depending on the kind of PLC you can have some info and maybe access to I/O data.
2. The connection is straightforward like any other TCP/IP device providing an IP and a port address, if the socket does not connect means there is nothing responding
3. If you are not connecting to an already working server in the PLC, as some noted in comments You should implement in the PLC program a server loop that answers to your requests, you have to check vendor documentation